# How do I keep only the last 10 observations in SAS once an if condition is met?

Tags: sas

How can I modify the below code to tell SAS that if trend is UP or Down then keep the last 10 observations in the dataset? The below code only keeps that particular observation, but I need to see the 10 observations before that, too. Thanks!

```
Data want;
set have;
if TrendDown=1 and ck1=1 and ck2=1 then Trend='Down';
if TrendUp=1 and ck1=1 and ck2=1 then Trend='Up';
if Trend='Up' or Trend='Down';
run;
```

Comment: Hi, In SAS you can't delete (or do something) for a certain observation based on the observations appearing later in the dataset. However, you can delete/keep them based on the earlier observations. So I think here you need to flip the dataset around. Do you have some variable like date which can be used for ordering the observations? I think you should have based on the nature of your question.

Comment: Yes I do have a date variable and a time variable. This is for intraday observations. So for each day I have multiple observations ranked by time. How would I do the flipping? Thanks so much.

Comment: What I am trying to do is find instances where prices keep going up or down for 10 consecutive observations (what I call trend). Then I want to keep only those 10 observations (however many there are in the dataset) and base my analysis only on those. It would be ideal if I could assign a group identifier to each such up or down trend so that when I do proc means I can tell SAS (via by or class) to do the analysis separately for each trend.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to show a little piece from  your data set in the question and point out the observations you want to keep.  I feel like keeping the instances where prices went up/down at least 10 consecutive times is not what is your original question.

Comment: Take a look at the lag function, you can use lag10 to get the value 10 observations back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does what you're asking, taking advantage of the current row number and the POINT statement to read the previous 9 rows and the current row.  I've also asked it to set the current value of the Trend variable to all 10 rows, using the RETAIN statement.  Hope this helps.

```
Data want;
set have;
if TrendDown=1 and ck1=1 and ck2=1 then Trend='Down';
if TrendUp=1 and ck1=1 and ck2=1 then Trend='Up';
if Trend in ('Up','Down') then do i = -9 to 0;
    obnum = _n_+i;
    set have point=obnum;
    retain Trend;
    drop i;
    output;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked well when I deleted the retain statement (it was creating many duplicates). Is there a way to group each 10-observation trend (up or down) so I can do analysis using proc means (by or class statement) for each of those separately. Thank you.

Comment: I was able to solve the follow-up question in my comment above. Thanks for your help again!